# How to send sms challenge in Okta Java SDK

Tags: java, sms, okta

How can I send an sms challenge to the phone number given while enrolling to the factor using Okta Java API? My code is as follows:

```
    Client client =  Clients.builder()
            .setOrgUrl(hostname)
            .setClientCredentials(new TokenClientCredentials(apikey))
            .build();

    User user = client.getUser(email);
    FactorList factors = user.listFactors();
    Factor factor = null;
    for (Factor f : factors) {
        if (f.getFactorType().toString().equals(authFactor)) {
            factor = f;
        }
    }
    if (factor != null && factor.getStatus().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("active")) {
        VerifyFactorRequest verifyFactorRequest = client.instantiate(VerifyFactorRequest.class);
        // send sms challenge
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.

```
VerifyFactorRequest verifyFactorRequest = client.instantiate(VerifyFactorRequest.class);
assert factor != null;
factor.verify(verifyFactorRequest);
```

Comment: This is aggravating. The [SDK docs show a verification after the challenge has been issued](https://github.com/okta/okta-sdk-java#verify-a-factor), that is, they call `.setPassCode("123456")` on the `verifyFactorRequest`. The only hint that the challenge operation is the same methods is that the [api endpoint is the same `/users/${userId}/factors/${factorId}/verify`](https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/factors/#issue-an-sms-factor-challenge), just without the POST body. Kudos to you.